# One giant table or Multiple smaller tables, Efficiency/Good Practice

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I'm a Computer Science and Engineering student.  I have not taken any classes on database design so I apologize if this is a basic question. Also I'm new to this website so I apologize if this is the wrong place to post this question.

I have a table that looks like this:

```
+--------+--------+------------+-------------+------+----------+--------+
| userID | typeID | categoryID | description | date | budgeted | actual |
+--------+--------+------------+-------------+------+----------+--------+
```

**Question:** Is it efficient to store every user's transactions into this one giant table or should I make smaller tables of transactions, one table for each user.  If it is the later how should I go about doing this? The only way I can think of is to dynamically name each table when the user is created but I've read this is not a good practice

Comment: one table for each user?? And how you think that is going to improve  performance? You current table structure looks fine to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's efficient to store them in one table.

If it gets big (e.g. 10M rows) you can start thinking about [partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning.html).

If the data is accumulated over time (customer orders) the partitioning is usually done by date (month, year ...) instead of the user.